# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, curl

```
<?php
include 'includes/config.php';

function do_curl($start_index, $stop_index) {

    // Do query here to get all pages with ids between start index and stop index

    $query = "SELECT * FROM fanpages WHERE idnum >= $start_index and idnum <= $stop_index";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $fanpages_query[] = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$row['page_id'];
    }
    return $fanpages_query;   
}

$fanpages = do_curl($_GET['start_index'], $_GET['stop_index']);
$fanpages_count = count($fanpages);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $fanpages_count; $i++)
{
    $url = $fanpages[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}
do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} while($running > 0);

echo "results: <br>";
for($i = 0; $i < $fanpages_count; $i++)
{
    $results = json_decode(curl_multi_getcontent($curl_arr[$i]));
    echo("Page Name: ".($results->name)."<br>"."Likes: ".($results->likes)."<br>"."ID: ".($results->id)."<br><br>");
}
echo 'done';


?>
```

And like you can see almost everything works, the only problem is with the Array's, I asked a question related to this like two hours ago but the answer that I got doesn't work for me. So the problem is that the combination of do_curl and the `while` in it with `$fanpages` arrays list is not working. every time I'm trying to run the script i get the proper number of pages, proper number of data but it throws me this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\curltest.php on line 46

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\curltest.php on line 46

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\curltest.php on line 46
```

My bet is that the arrays aren't parsed like they need to be | $fanpages = array('http://graph.facebook.com/1111111', 'http://graph.facebook.com/222222222', 'http://graph.facebook.com/333333333'); | because if I write them manually everything works.

**EDIT: There was a script error on:**

```
 $fanpages_query[] = '\'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$row['page_id']."'";
```

and i just removed the \' and now its throwing:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in C:\xampp\htdocs\curltest.php on line 48
```

After adding var_dump:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["error"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["type"]=> string(20) "GraphMethodException" ["message"]=> string(24) "Unsupported get request." } } string(78) "{"error":{"type":"GraphMethodException","message":"Unsupported get request."}}" NULL
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in C:\xampp\htdocs\curltest.php on line 48
```

Comment: it seems pretty obvious.  have you tried to var_dump($results) to see what is actually being returned?  or just echo _curl_multi_getcontent($curl_arr[$i])_.  why just assume something is there...

Comment: Why are the URLs enclosed in single quotes? And if the `var_dump($result)` doesn't give any indication, remove the json_decode first to see if any content was returned.

Comment: "I asked a question related to this like two hours ago but the answer that I got doesn't work for me." First, two hours is a pretty short time to wait. Considering timezones and work schedules, many available experts may not have seen your question yet. Second, if your previous question deals with the same issue, you should edit it until you get the result you want, instead of cluttering the site with duplicate questions.

Comment: yea i removed the single quotes and wrote a var_dump and that's what i get now: object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["error"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["type"]=> string(20) "GraphMethodException" ["message"]=> string(24) "Unsupported get request." } } string(78) "{"error":{"type":"GraphMethodException","message":"Unsupported get request."}}" NULL
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in C:\xampp\htdocs\curltest.php on line 48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$results = json_decode(curl_multi_getcontent($curl_arr[$i]));
```

The JSON decoding is failing.  Change it to this and post the results so we can get some more info:

```
$results = json_decode($raw_results = curl_multi_getcontent($curl_arr[$i]));
var_dump($results, $raw_results, !$results?json_last_error():null);
```

#### EDIT 1

According to the comments you aren't getting any data back.  Is there a reason you aren't using code like that which is provided in the [`curl_multi_exec()` manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)?

```
$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
```

Comment: results:
NULL NULL int(0)
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\curltest.php on line 48

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\curltest.php on line 48

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\curltest.php on line 48 AND I Know that its failing but it was OK when i had the arrays for $fanpages written manually like i wrote on the end of the question.

Comment: NOTICE that after i fixed the error (EDITED the question with the error description on the end) i get this error: object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["error"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["message"]=> string(68) "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 189933731049'" } } string(116) "{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 189933731049'"}}" NULL
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in C:\xampp\htdocs\curltest.php on line 48

Comment: Regarding to EDIT1: Like i said i think there is no need in to use another curl code because this code is working perfect when the arrays is written manually | $fanpages = array('http://graph.facebook.com/1111111', 'http://graph.facebook.com/222222222', 'http://graph.facebook.com/333333333');

Comment: then var_dump the array and see what's going on in there.

Comment: Thanks Dereleased, while 50% was too busy at shouting how bad i asked the question you helped me and now it works. ;)

Comment: I honestly don't understand the negativity.  There was enough information in your question to start stabbing at it and I'm glad we got there.  I'm sure that if what I had said had appeared obvious to you, you would have done it already, and would have told me so when I suggested it.  This is a place for questions, not for everyone to sit around being smug about what experts we are.